# jQuery set width of element to value of array

Tags: jquery, arrays, width

I have some basic markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class=".content"></div>
    <div class=".content"></div>
    <div class=".content"></div>
    <div class=".content"></div>
    <div class=".content"></div>
    <div class=".content"></div>
</div>
```

and the following jQuery code:

```
var listWidth = [];
    $('.content').each(function(){
        listWidth.push($(this).width());
                console.log(listWidth);
    });
```

This returns:

```
[200, 540, 200, 540, 200, 540]
```

How do I set the width of the parent element to the sum of the values within the array, so in this case 2220?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var width = 0;
$.each(listWidth, function(){
   width += this;
});

$("#container").width(width);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var divWidth = 0;
$(listWidth).each(function(){
    divWidth += Number(this);
});

$('#container').css('width',divWidth);
```